# Как понять, почему не отвечают сервисы/почему сервер не доступен?

Tags: nginx, сервер, администрирование, iptables, azure

Периодически без всяких причин может заглючить сервер. Два типа глюков:

1) Машина в принципе перестаёт отвечать. Запросы не идут к ней. По ssh не зайти.

2) На машину зайти можно зайти, но она тупит. К примеру, сервисы вроде запущены, но работать с ними не получаются. Тот же [redis](/questions/tagged/redis) или [consul](/questions/tagged/consul). В процессах висят, но при попытке выполнить любой `cli` запрос, он тупо виснет. Даже операция `find` подвисает. [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) проксирует некоторые запросы к [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) сервисам. Они тоже отваливаются по таймауту. Лимиты на серверах большие (ulimit, ограничение на сокеты и т.п.).

CPU не жрётся, на диске место есть, оперативки хватает. После ребута машины, логично, что всё ок.

Все виртуалки с **Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS**.

В какую сторону копать и что смотреть, если это снова случится?

Я не разбираюсь в iptables, но я сохранил список во время проблемы и после:

Когда присутствует проблема, то есть такие правила:

```
Chain RESET (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with tcp-reset

Chain PROHIBIT (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Они могут быть причиной? Если да, то как найти виновника? Единственное, что я нашёл в логах:

```
Jul 15 06:25:01 journey-test python3[1090]: 2018/07/15 06:25:01.935420 INFO Successfully added Azure fabric firewall rules
Jul 15 06:25:01 journey-test python3[1090]: 2018/07/15 06:25:01.963119 INFO Firewall rules:
Jul 15 06:25:01 journey-test python3[1090]: Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
Jul 15 06:25:01 journey-test python3[1090]:     pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
Jul 15 06:25:01 journey-test python3[1090]: Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
Jul 15 06:25:01 journey-test python3[1090]:     pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
Jul 15 06:25:01 journey-test python3[1090]: Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
Jul 15 06:25:01 journey-test python3[1090]:     pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
Jul 15 06:25:01 journey-test python3[1090]:        0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            168.63.129.16        owner UID match 0
Jul 15 06:25:01 journey-test python3[1090]:        0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            168.63.129.16        ctstate INVALID,NEW
```

**UPD:** в **/etc/waagent.conf** нашёл `OS.EnableFirewall=y`. На старых виртуалках, где всё норм, такого правила нет. На всех новых виртуалках есть. Azure поменял дефолтное поведение своего агента. Сейчас он может менять правила фаервола. 
Не знаю, может ли это быть причиной.

Comment: А оперативка? .

Comment: @andreymal там тоже всё норм.

Comment: почитать логи сервера, проверить использование swap, оперативной памяти. Если есть средства мониторинга, то момент "тупизма" будет виден на графиках. Проверить диск на ошибки.

Comment: @diproart сейчас тоже самое произошло. В логах ничего опасного нет. И это не на одной машине происходит, вряд ли что-то с диском. На графиках в админке Azure ничего аномального не вижу.

Comment: @diproart после рестарта фаервола всё норм. У меня есть список iptables во время этой проблемы, но я в этих правилах совсем не шарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. На серваках крутится Азуровский WALinuxAgent.
2. Я заметил в логах, что он зачем-то лезет править фаервол.
3. С каких-то пор они поменяли дефолтное поведение агента. Это я случайно заметил сравнив `/etc/waagent.conf` на старых машинах и на новых. Там теперь `OS.EnableFirewall=y`, он теперь может править фаервол.
4. Я использую `apf` для настройки доступа.
5. В какой-то момент у них возник конфликт.
6. После установки в `false` этого флага `OS.EnableFirewall=n` проблема больше не повторяется.

Небольшое дополнение. Вероятно, при поднятии новой машины я забыл убрать **basic** настройки фаервола.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как следствие, их агент, вероятно, переопределял мои настройки в `apf` и ломали доступ по ssh и т.п.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]